# Trigger bootstrap modal after django form submission

Tags: django, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

How can I trigger the bootstrap modal to popup after my django form was submitted?

In my index.html template I have a standard looking modal like this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

below in the same index.html I have a django form

```
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <ul id="robul">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <li id="name" name="{{ form.name.name }}" class="form-control">{{ form.name }}</li>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <li id="email" class="form-control">{{ form.email }}</li>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <li id="contactmessage" class="form-control">{{ form.contactmessage }}</li>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </ul>
```

in my view.py it looks like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.FormName(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get(
                'name', '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get(
                'email', '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('contactmessage', '')

            template = get_template('contact_template.txt')
            context = {'name': contact_name,
            'email': contact_email,
            'contactmessage': form_content,}
            content = template.render(context)
            mail = EmailMessage("New contact form submission", content, "Some Name" +'', ['somegmail@gmail.com'],
            headers = {'Reply-To': "noreply@gmail.com" })
            mail.send()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The modal and JS code to trigger it live in a different context than your Django form submission code. Rendering `'index.html'` is basically starting fresh when you're returning from your form submission, so it essentially amounts to showing the modal on page load. But, maybe you only want to show it after a successful submit. What you'll have to do is have some JS code to show the modal on page load, and have something in your template rendering context to conditionally render that. Here's what I'm thinking:

In `index.html`:

```
{% if successful_submit %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#exampleModal").modal('show');
        });
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

In your view function, add the `successful_submit` context variable to your return:

```
return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form, 'successful_submit': True})
```

Now, that `<script>` tag will only be rendered if `successful_submit` is `True`, which will only be set after a successful form `POST`.

Comment: it sounds very logical what you write and I entered the code as you suggested. but still the modal won't show up after filling the form succesfully

Comment: Can you check if the `<script>` tag is rendering? Do you have any browser console errors? I could have a typo in there somewhere.

Comment: my bad, I called the script tag before I called the jquery script. Works now! thank you for your help!

Comment: I tried this solution and my modal loads even when the form isn't filled, on loading my `contacts.html` page.What might i be doing wrong?

Comment: @DennisGathagu It's been a long time since I've looked at this question and answer. I'd suggest creating a new question with your full problem and the community and I can take a look.